# WPF Invisible CheckBox

Tags: wpf, vb.net, checkbox

A checkbox placed in a toolbar is not visible (.NET 4.0 Win 7.0 Aero)

```
        Dim vLabel As New Label
        vLabel.Content = "Tenant"

        Dim TenantDP As New DockPanel
        Dim TenantCB As New CheckBox
        With TenantCB
            .Content = vLabel
            .Name = "WebsiteUser_TenantCB"
            .ToolTip = "Check if the user is a tenant"
            .VerticalAlignment = Windows.VerticalAlignment.Center
            .HorizontalAlignment = Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left
            .Padding = New Thickness(5, 0, 0, 0)
            .BorderBrush = New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black)
            .IsEnabled = True
        End With

        RegisterControl(Website_User_Grid, TenantCB, TenantCB.Name.ToString)
        TenantDP.Children.Add(TenantCB)
        vToolBar.Items.Add(TenantDP)
        vToolBar.Items.Add(TS_Separator)
```

I can get the box to display (until the mouse goes over it) using Border,

```
            .BorderBrush = New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black)
```

but not the check - the actual control works fine, but the users just can't see it. Any ideas?

Comment: I dont understand this... **but not the check - the actual control works fine, but the users just can't see it.**... are you saying the `tickmark` of checkbox isnt appearing? or the label of the checkbox is not appearing?

Comment: Yup - the tickmark is not showing, even if I change the back colour. The label (or the text directly as Content) are fine. The checkbox will display with BorderBrush applied then vanish when the mouse is over it.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a problem with a theme!